# Number of Surjective functions. How does $2! S(r, 2) = 2^r−2$ for $|A| = r, |B| = 2$ where $r \ge 2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Currently prepping for a Discrete Mathematics exam and stumbled across a question from last year's exam:

> Suppose that $|A|= r$ and $|B|=2$, where $r \geq 2$ . Find all values of $r$ for which the number of surjective functions from $A$ to $B$ coincides with the number of injective functions from $B$ to $A$. Give a proof that your
>   list is complete.

From what I know, I would have used the formula $k!S(n,k)$ to find the number of surjective functions and the falling factorial $r(2) := r(r-1)$ for the number of injective functions, but in scoping out the answer I came across this:

$$2!S(r,2) = 2^r−2~\text{for}~|A| = r, |B| = 2~\text{where}~r \geq  2$$

This was used in the proof to show that the values of $r$ were $2$ and $3$ by using inequalities which is fine, but I just wanted a brush up on how $2!S(r,2) = 2^r-2$.

(I seriously just write out the Stirling triangle every time if I just need the number of surjective functions without proving anything in particular, and I am not seeing the relation straight away from looking at the definition.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|B| = 2$, the functions $A \to B$ that fail to be surjective are exactly the constant ones. There are $|B|^{|A|} = 2^r$ total functions $A \to B$ and $|B| = 2$ constant ones, so there are $2^r - 2$ surjections $A \to B$. An injective function $B \to A$ is just an ordered pair $(r, r')$ with $r\not = r'$; writing $B = \{1, 2\},$ the identification sends $(r, r')$ to the map $1 \to r, 2 \to r'$. Thus there are $r(r - 1)$ injections $B \to A$.

Thus we want the set of $r$ with $2^r - 2 = r(r - 1)$. For $r \geq 4$, we have $2^r - 2 \geq r^2 - 2 > r^2 - r$. The remaining cases can be done by hand.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^r$ functions from $A$ to $B$ since there are two possible images for each element of $A$.  The only functions that aren't surjective are the constant functions, of which there are two, since for any nonconstant function, both elements of $B$ are the image of some element of $A$.  Hence $2^r-2$ surjective functions.

More generally, if $B$ had $s$ elements, there would be $s^r$ functions from $A$ to $B$.  A function is not surjective if some element of $B$ is not the image of any element of $A$.  Let $S_{\{x\}}$ be the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ in which $x\in B$ is not in the image of $A$.  We have $\lvert S_{\{x\}}\rvert=(s-1)^r$ and $s$ choices of the element $x$.  But $s^r-s(s-1)^r$ is not correct (unless $s\le2$) since, for example, functions in which neither $x$ nor $y$ is in the image of $A$ have been subtracted twice.  Let $S_{\{x,y\}}=S_{\{x\}}\cap S_{\{y\}}$ be the set of such functions.  We have $\lvert S_{\{x,y\}}\rvert=(s-2)^r$ and $\binom{s}{2}$ choices of the set $\{x,y\}$ of elements omitted from the image.  Adding these back in gives $s^r-s(s-1)^r+\binom{s}{2}(s-2)^r$, which, however, is still not correct (unless $s\le3$) since functions in which three elements are omitted from the image of $A$ are still not correctly accounted for.  The principle of inclusion-exclusion tells us to proceed by alternately adding and subtracting the functions with $k$ elements omitted from the image of $A$, where $k$ ranges from $0$ to $s$.  This gives
$$
s^r-s(s-1)^r+\binom{s}{2}(s-2)^r-\binom{s}{3}(s-3)^r+\ldots+(-1)^{s-1}\binom{s}{s-1}1^r+(-1)^s\binom{s}{s}0^r
$$
surjective functions.  This reduces to $2^r-2$ when $s=2$.

**Added:** Divide this last expression by $s!$ to obtain a formula for $S(r,s)$, something that is useful to have in addition to the recurrence you've been using.  The reason for the factor $\frac{1}{s!}$ is that each partition of $A$ into nonempty parts is associated with $s!$ different surjective functions from $A$ to $B$, one for each way of assigning the elements of $B$ to the parts.

Comment: One quibble:  As your first paragraph shows, whether $s^r - s(s - 1)^r$ is correct depends on $s$.  If the OP had not asked about Stirling numbers of the second kind, this is the approach I would have taken.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig : did you mean second paragraph?  I hope the added text clarifies that this really is tied in with Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: I was referring to the second paragraph.  When you say that $s^r - s(s - 1)^r$ is not correct, you are implicitly assuming that $s > 2$.  When you say that $s^r - s(s - 1)^4 + \binom{s}{2}(s - 2)^r$ is not correct, you are implicitly assuming that $s > 3$.  That said, your answer is useful, all the more so now that you have indicated the connection between the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle argument and Stirling numbers of the second kind. (+1)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig :   Thanks for catching those issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Stirling number of the second kind, denoted $S(n, k)$, is the number of ways to partition a set with $n$ elements into $k$ non-empty subsets.  Hence, $S(r, 2)$ is the number of ways of partitioning a set with $r$ elements into a non-empty subset and its complement.  Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_r\}$, where $r \geq 2$.  Any partition of $A$ into two subsets is determined by which of the other $r - 1$ elements in the set are in the same subset as $a_r$.  A subset of $A$ that contains $a_r$ is the union of $\{a_r\}$ with one of the $2^{r - 1}$ subsets of $A - \{a_r\} = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{r - 1}\}$.  However, we require that the complement of the set that contains $a_r$ be non-empty.  Therefore, we cannot take $A = \{a_r\} \cup \{a_1, a_2, \ldots a_{r - 1}\}$ as one of the sets in the partition, so there are $S(r, 2) = 2^{r - 1} - 1$ partitions of $A$ into two non-empty subsets.

A surjective function $f: A \to B$, where $B = \{b_1, b_2\}$ is determined by partitioning $A$ into two non-empty subsets, mapping each element in one of those subsets to $b_1$ and mapping each element in the other subset to $b_2$.  For each partition, there are $2!$ ways of assigning an image of each subset, depending on whether the elements subset containing $a_r$ are mapped to $b_1$ and the elements in its complement are mapped to $b_2$ or vice versa.  Hence, there are $2!S(r, 2) = 2!(2^r - 1) = 2^r - 2$ surjective functions from $A$ to $B$.